# Lighting with draw mode

Tags: rendering, materials, lighting, shader-nodes, draw-mode

How can I brighten my work with Drawing Mode? Except with the Light I show in the 2nd photo.

[image]

[image]

Do I have a chance to illuminate the drawn with Draw Mode like Bezier?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your GP object not affected by light disable *Use Lights* on every GP layer:

[image]

If you want white color to be exactly white, I think it is better to disable color management. To do this, set View transform to "Standard":

[image]

[image]

Comment: do we have a chance to increase this light?

Comment: I do not understand. Disabling lights makes it shadless, so that initial color is shown, without shadows darkened the colors.

Comment: On the contrary, can I increase the brightness of the light?

Comment: Check my update in the post

Comment: Thanks, my problems are solved.
I will ask one more thing. Can I add emission to the line drawn with Draw Mode?

Comment: I think not, but where some effects in GP, like glow, are available. In this site, better ask one question per tread, so that others can have a chance to answer.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I solved all the problems.